Second-order equations of motion for higher derivative gravity?
We know that Lovelock gravity is the most general theory of gravity possible for Lagrangians which depend only on the metric tensor and the Riemann tensor
\begin{equation*}
L = L \left(g_{\alpha\beta}, R_{\mu\nu\rho\sigma} \right)
\end{equation*}
and which lead to second order equations of motion.
My question is this -- if the Lagrangian also contains derivatives of the Riemann tensor
\begin{equation*}
L = L \left(g_{\alpha\beta}, R_{\mu\nu\rho\sigma}, \nabla_{\lambda_1} R_{\mu\nu\rho\sigma}, \nabla_{\lambda_1} \nabla_{\lambda_2} R_{\mu\nu\rho\sigma}, \cdots \right)
\end{equation*}
then is it possible to determine which Lagrangians of the above form lead to second order equations of motion?

Lovelock's theorem characterizes the field equations, not the Lagrangians. This means that if you have a higher order Lagrangian with second order EoMs, that's just an alternative Lagrangian for some Lovelock gravity theory.

Lovelock's theorem only talks about field equations which depend on the metric only up to its second derivative (or equivalently the Riemann tensor). If we include third and higher derivatives of the metric (or equivalently derivatives of the Riemann tensor), can we extend Lovelock's theorem to determine all the possible second order field equations? That's my question.
